# Split table row and remmember every cell by regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

Source text is:

```
gi0/1 1G-Fiber -- -- -- -- Down -- -- Access
gi0/2 1G-Fiber -- -- -- -- Down -- -- 
gi0/3 1G-Fiber -- -- -- -- Down -- -- 
gi0/4 1G-Fiber -- -- -- -- Down -- -- 
gi0/5 1G-Fiber -- -- -- -- Down -- -- 

gi0/0/1 1G-Fiber -- -- -- -- Down -- --  Access
gi0/0/2 1G-Fiber -- -- -- -- Down -- -- 
gi0/0/3 1G-Fiber -- -- -- -- Down -- -- 
gi0/0/4 1G-Fiber -- -- -- -- Down -- -- 
gi0/0/5 1G-Fiber -- -- -- -- Down -- --
```

My work code is:

```
var re = /(([\w]{2})[\/\d]{1,})\s+([\w\-\.\s]+){1,}[\r\n]/ig;
while ( (MyArray = re.exec(text)) != null ){
```

// here i want get array with follow values (MyArray)

```
[0] [matched string]
[1] gi0/1 (gi0/0/1)
[2] gi
[3] 1G-Fiber
[4] -- 
[5] --
[6] --
[7] --
[8] Down
[9] --
[10] --
[11] Access (only for 1st and 6th row)
```

// but get (MyArray)

```
[0] [matched string]
[1] gi0/1 (gi0/0/1)
[2] gi
[3] "s" OR "empty"
}
```

Online example  - http://regexr.com?31ilv

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why not just split each line at the spaces?  `MyArray = line.split(" ")`

Comment: Because I want to understand how you can remember repeating sequence with regeexp

Comment: The regex here doesn't match the one at http://regexr.com?31ilv.  Try this: http://regexr.com?31in9.  This gives you the full match, with still just 3 groups.  A single regex will always produce the same number of groups.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var subject = "gi0/1 1G-Fiber -- -- -- -- Down -- -- Access";
        //var subject = "gi0/1 1G-Fiber -- -- -- -- Down -- --";
        var regex = /([^\s]*)\s([^\s]*)\s([^\s]*)\s([^\s]*)\s([^\s]*)\s([^\s]*)\s([^\s]*)\s([^\s]*)\s([^\s]*)\s*([^\s]*)/;
        var result = regex.exec(subject);
        document.write("<ol>");
        for (var i = 1; i < result.length; i++) {
            document.write("<li>'<i>" + result[i] + "<\/i>'<\/li>");
        }
        document.write("<\/ol>");
    </script>
```

In case the source string has no "Access" postfix, this regex creates an array with an empty last element. Another strategy could be to use the String.search function and iterate over the source string.